# What is causing duplicate builds of same target in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

We are seeing duplicate builds of the same target in Bazel and wondering what could cause this.

Here is a sample output:

```
[52,715 / 55,135] 12 action running
    Bazel package: some-pkg - Target: a_target - Generating files at bazel-out/host/bin/some-pkg/a_target_generate [for host]; 264s remote-cache, processwrapper-sandbox
    Bazel package: some-pkg - Target: a_target - Generating files at bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/some-pkg/a_target_generate; 264s remote-cache, processwrapper-sandbox
    ...
```

We have not been able to identify the issue. It looks like this is only happening on Linux but not on Macs.

The target `a_target` is a `custom_rule` target. It should be platform independent.

```
custom_rule = rule(
    attrs = dict(
       ...
        _custom_rule_java_binary = attr.label(
            cfg = "host",
            default = Label("//tools/bazel/build/rules/custom-rule:custom_rule_bin"),
            executable = True,
        ),
        _singlejar = attr.label(
            cfg = "host",
            default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar"),
            executable = True,
            allow_files = True,
        ),
    ),
    implementation = ...,
)
```

`custom_rule_bin` is defined as follow:

```
java_library(
    name = "custom_rule",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = [
        ...,
    ],
)

java_binary(
    name = "custom_rule_bin",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    main_class = "...",
    runtime_deps = [
        "@org_slf4j_simple",
        ":custom_rule",
        "//some-pkg:some_pkg", # same some-pkg where a_target is built twice
    ],
)
```

The difference is that one says "*for host*" and the other doesn't. Anyone knows what the extra "*for host*" build is?

I do have a feeling that it's somehow related to the `cfg` attribute on the custom rule. This is likely coming from some example code. We use the same value on all our rules which generate code. This custom rule is special because it requires code from the application being built by Bazel to run and generate additional code.

Any insights appreciated why `host` would be wrong and what would be the correct value.

Any ideas/tips how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one note is that the host configuration is being mostly deprecated, and "exec" is usually preferred. Some info about that is here: https://bazel.build/rules/rules#configurations.

What's happening is that that target is being depended upon in multiple configurations, and so bazel will build that target in each configuration. You can use cquery to figure out what's going on

As a very simple example:

```
genrule(
  name = "gen_bin",
  outs = ["bin"],
  srcs = [":gen_lib"],
  exec_tools = [":gen_tool"],
  cmd = "touch $@",
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_tool",
  outs = ["tool"],
  srcs = [":gen_lib"],
  cmd = "touch $@",
)

genrule(
  name = "gen_lib",
  outs = ["lib"],
  cmd = "touch $@; sleep 10",
)
```

Building `bin`, bazel runs the gen_lib genrule twice (in parallel):

```
$ bazel build bin
INFO: Analyzed target //:bin (5 packages loaded, 16 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[1 / 5] 2 actions running
    Executing genrule //:gen_lib; 1s linux-sandbox
    Executing genrule //:gen_lib; 1s linux-sandbox
```

`bazel config` gives the configurations that are currently in the in-memory build graph:

```
$ bazel config
Available configurations:
5b39bc31deb1f1d37f1f858e7eec3964394eacce5bede4456dd59d417af4a6e9 (exec)
723da02ae6d0c5577e98242c8f06ca1bd1c6d7b295c97345ac31b844bfe8f79c
8960923b9e7dc13418be101268efd8e57d80283213d18174705345598b699c6b
fd805cc1de357c04c7abac1b40bae600e3d9ee56a8d17af0c28b5031ca09bfb9 (host)
```

then `cquery`:

```
$ bazel cquery "rdeps(//..., gen_lib)"
INFO: Analyzed 3 targets (0 packages loaded, 1 target configured).
INFO: Found 3 targets...
//:gen_lib (5b39bc3)
//:gen_lib (8960923)
//:gen_tool (5b39bc3)
//:gen_bin (8960923)
//:gen_tool (8960923)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.052s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
```

(cquery gives the first 7 digits of the configuration hash)

`--output=graph` gives a dot graph which is a little more useful:

```
$ bazel cquery "rdeps(//..., gen_lib)" --output=graph > /tmp/graph
$ xdot /tmp/graph
```

[image: cquery graph]

So gen_bin is in the target configuration (8960923), and it depends on gen_lib, so gen_lib will also be built in the target configuration.

gen_bin also depends on gen_tool via the exec_tools attribute, and exec_tools builds everything in the exec configuration (5b39bc3).

gen_tool also depends on gen_lib, and since gen_tool is in the exec configuration, a version of gen_lib is built in the exec configuration.

(There's also another version of gen_tool in the target configuration in the output, and that's an artifact of using `//...` in the "universe" argument of rdeps(), since `//...` will capture every target. Similarly, doing `bazel build //...` would cause gen_tool to be built twice.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It confirms a hypothesis around configurations. It sounds like we should force all tools to `cfg="target"` in order to avoid multiple configurations. I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: Putting tools in the target configuration might work, but it might only be by coincidence. If your target configuration changes (e.g. for cross compilation), or if your exec platform changes, then your tools might stop working. I think what you might check first is to make sure all your tools are in the exec configuration (since having some tools in exec and some in target can cause the above behavior too), unless you know for sure that your tools and your top-level targets (i.e. those targets in the target configuration) share dependencies.

Comment: Also, changing other flags like --compilation_mode (i.e. for the target configuration) between dbg and opt would cause all your tools to be rebuilt, and there are other considerations like wanting all your tools to be in opt while your target is in dbg.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some analysis/experiments. Our tools and top-level targets share the same dependencies. It's all Java so shouldn't have needs for different configuration.

Comment: Solution is indeed to see if you can put the tools into the `target` configuration, which is usually ok for Java based tools.